# What are the most influental groups advocating for a global government?

Tags: globalization

Are there political groups (grassroots or organized) that advocate for a global government, and if so, which are the most influental by number of members and/or in financial terms?

Comment: Libertarians (used to?) reject borders and want a common government: minimal.

Comment: @dandavis "Libertarians (used to?) reject borders ..." Really? They were for example not against immigration? If by chance you have direct sources for this I would be interested in getting to know them.

Comment: open borders and legal crack for children, what's not to love?  https://www.lp.org/issues/immigration/

Comment: Wanting free travel is completely distinct to wanting global government. You can have free travel, trade, and immigration in a decentralised setting if everyone agrees by treaty, or imposed top-down by a world government.

Answer (score -4):

At various point in history, Muslims, Christians and Communists all have converting the whole world as part of their manifest destiny, and mission statement.

Comment: global government is different than global dominance

Comment: @devconcept: it is exactly the same idea...  how would anyone propose to govern globally without global domination?  The question is what kind of people/group has that tendency....   I think it is a reasonable observation to make..

Comment: true but "domination" traditionally developed by those groups has been economic or military domination preserving or expanding the dominant's borders. The government the OP is probably referring is the new globalist agenda which is a cultural dominance "erasing borders" which is kinda different because without borders is hard to figure out who is dominating the others.

Comment: @devconcept: not every culture / ideology is interested in global domination...   Erasing border ... erasing cultural identity are also the pet projects of communism, christianity and islam...  we don't see that because we  live in a judeo-christian world, but everything before has already been erased...

Comment: true again but you need to be more specific. Islam and christianity aimed at cultural identity change but not deliberated, they just aimed at imposing their religion which they believed to be the true one. There were no deep studies on how human culture worked on those times. Comunism didn't make this it's pet project until the fall of the Berlin Wall because their arguments became obsolete. Soros is famous for his globalist agenda and spending a lot of money on this. There is no point of asking about global government if you are not referring to the current one.

Comment: @devconcept:  Soros  didn't invent his idea in a vacuum.  There are a lot of advantages to erasing borders and erasing cultural identities (especially if you keep your own).  By erasing other people's identity and culture, you gain the ability to tell them what is what.  and they won't even know that they are dancing to your tune.  As long as you are doing the erasing, you are in the thought leader position.

Comment: It was started by [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Gramsci) and then developed by this [philosophical school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_School). You can read their books and see for yourself and if you notice this stuff is pretty old.

Answer (score -4):

The groups come and go, the names change, their tactics for trying to convince the masses vary, but the underlying motives for these Globalists are always the same.  They want to convince the world that they are the smartest people and they know the best way to run everything and if the rest of us would just give up control of everything to them we would all be better off.
What they know would happen for sure is that their group would become very rich and powerful at the expense of anyone who got in their way.  For Russia it used to be the Czar, then the Soviets, now Putin and his associates.  For Germany it was the Nazi party.  In the E.U. various groups vying for ultimate power.  In the U.S. the high end of the Political class, (from both Parties) along with various other rich groups, including Hollywood and Labor Unions.  Then they try to get together under some globalist umbrella.  In the 1970's and 80s it was unilateral nuclear disarmament for the US.  Now it is under the Climate Change umbrella.  Both movements have legitimate elements, but present opportunities for power consolidation of control in the hands of a few in the name of global harmony. ESG scores for financial transactions are another ruse being used by wealthy institutions to try and create a monopoly of money exchange and take control of global interactions